# How can I force caching a video file on nginx

Tags: ubuntu, video, cache, nginx

I have two servers configured pretty much exactly similarly. One is my production server, and the other is my staging server. The nginx config on both are copies of each other except for the name of the server (and whereever else I use the server name)

Here is the config from my staging server.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name *.johnvarghese.info johnvarghese.info;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/johnvarghese.info.ssl/star.johnvarghese.info.bundle.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/johnvarghese.info.ssl/star.johnvarghese.info.key;

  server_name support.johnvarghese.info;
  return 301 "$scheme://johnvarghese.info/support${request_uri}";
}

server {
  listen 443;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/johnvarghese.info.ssl/star.johnvarghese.info.bundle.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/johnvarghese.info.ssl/star.johnvarghese.info.key;

  server_name *.johnvarghese.info johnvarghese.info;

  passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/wrappers/ruby;
  passenger_enabled on;
  root /var/www/johnvarghese.info/current/public;

  location ~* \.(mp4|ogg|webm)$ {
    expires 10d;
    add_header Cache-Control "max-age=864000";
  }

}
```

The staging server is called johnvarghese.info. On the production server, I replaced all instances of johnvarghese.info with the servername.com.

The lines I am interested is the last three lines in the config - I just want to cache the webm video file (which I repeat playing in a loop). It works perfectly on the staging server. Once the video is downloaded, I can turn off wireless networking on my laptop and the video keeps looping forever with nor further download required. The response code in the console is 206 every time starting from the second time. The server is not hit anymore.

On the production server the server is hit everytime the video is looped. The response code is 304 (not modified). If I turn of wireless networking on my laptop, when the video completes it current play, it stops because it cannot download it again for the repetition.

Why does the same configuration

```
  location ~* \.(mp4|ogg|webm)$ {
    expires 10d;
    add_header Cache-Control "max-age=864000";
  }
```

work differently on these similarly configured servers? I want to make the production server work just like the staging server. What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: What you’re configuring is client-side caching. Keep in mind that, if your files are too large, most browsers will probably not cache them. /edit: And please do what harrymc requested: Include the headers from both server and client for requests in both environments in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rather look at the headers received by the client browser, as the caching is done at the client browser rather than at the server. Nginx can add its own headers which may conflict with yours, depending on your server setup and added Nginx modules.

For further analysis, add a dump of the headers received by the client browser in both
the cases, where it worked and where it didn't.
This comparison might give us the answer to the mystery.

See this post for more ideas as to the cause : 
[Nginx add_header and cache control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19002567/nginx-add-header-and-cache-control).
The modules `more_set_headers` and `more_clear_headers` are suggested here in order to replace or clear the headers.

Comment: Thanks harrymc and Daniel B. I gladly assign the bounty points to you, not because your solution helped me fix it, but because you at least answered. Thats the good news. The better news is that my issue just disappeared. I think maybe it was because it has been ten days since the first time the video was downloaded. I was not able dump the headers here, because 1. I dont know how. and 2. The domain name I had for the staging server has expired and I cannot reproduce that perfectly. Anyway, alls well that ends well. I am able to start the video and disconnect. The video loops forever nicely.

Comment: If this happens again, you can dump the headers on Firefox using the [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) add-on. For a solution external to the browser, you could use the [Wireshark package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=wireshark) (Firebug is easier).

Comment: Or, better yet: Use a specialized proxy like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). It’s very handy to see what’s actually happening.

Comment: @DanielB: Fiddler is wonderful, but unfortunately it's a Microsoft product for Windows only.